# Can I farm out my Greater Steed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mount

If I use *[Find Greater Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-greater-steed)* and summon whatever beast from it, can I tell the creature to obey another player. i.e., let them ride it and do what they say, until I otherwise tell it to obey me instead?

Would that mount obey the other player I told it to? What if I was in danger: would it ignore my order to obey the player and do something I had not yet told it to do?

Comment: I don't know why I was expecting something completely different when I read the topic name; like a horse barbecue or milking it to drink or make cheese question.

Comment: I was also expecting something farm related, like forcing your steed to labour endlessly in a paddock

Answer (score 11):

The spell says:

> You control the mount in combat.

It is also loyal and intelligent.  You can also talk to the mount, well, use telepathy.  It understands your language, and you can communicate telepathically.

There is nothing else in the spell that dictates how the mount will behave.  It can be loyal without necessarily being obedient.  Maybe it views you with complete devotion and will follow you around like a puppy, fetching your slippers or whatever.  Or maybe it's completely loyal to you, but doesn't think you have the sense to come in out of the rain and thinks you need protection from yourself.

Jeremy Crawford, talking about *find steed*, [said](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/08/05/can-i-command-my-find-steed-mount-attack-seperately-while-not-mounted/) essentially, "you can command your steed however you would like and it will follow your commands to the best of its ability."  It's reasonable that that would apply to *find greater steed* as well.

You should definitely consult with your GM.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you mean by "beyond what you might expect from such a mount." As you noted, the mount is intelligent, having an intelligence of at least 6. It would be capable of following instructions that typical mounts might not be able to understand (such as protecting one particular person and following their instructions). What do you mean by "expected from such a mount"?

Comment: I can clean that language up a bit.

Comment: [Jeremy Crawford has talked about Find Steed here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/08/05/can-i-command-my-find-steed-mount-attack-seperately-while-not-mounted/), confirming that you can command it however you want when not mounted, and that it will attempt to follow your commands to the best of its ability. He also says [here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/722862974503813120): "Find Steed summons a mount that is under the paladin's control, regardless of the mount's Intelligence." It is definitely obedient and will attempt to follow your commands as well as it can.

Comment: Okay then!  I'll add that in.